# android drawOval compare to java drawOval

Tags: java, android

I need to know how to convert drawOval method in Java to drawOval in android. I have an example in Java that draw an oval like this :

`image.drawOval(core.x-coreRadius, core.y-coreRadius, 2*coreRadius, 2*coreRadius);`

where coreRadius is width of image / 4.

What i want to ask is, how to draw the oval like in the java example above in the android? I have read the documentation and found the parameter in each method is different, in Java, drawOval method is like this:

`drawOval(int x, int y, int width, int length)`

and in android, drawOval method is like this :

```
public RectF (float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
```

Please help me to convert the java drawOval method above to android drawOval method. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android the only difference is it takes a `RectF` instead of coordinates

```
canvas.drawOval(new RectF(core.x-coreRadius, core.y-coreRadius, core.x+coreRadius, core.y+coreRadius), new Paint());
```

Here is a simple example I found on google http://android.okhelp.cz/draw-oval-android-basic-example/

and of course android `Canvas` docs for `drawOval` [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawOval%28android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)